# When listening with delegate event on array of input, of type file, elements how do I read the file[0]?

Tags: html, jquery, file

I'm trying to get the file blob using the following function:

```
$('body').delegate('[id^="prod_img"]', 'click', function() 
{
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var selectedFile = $('#prod_img' + id).files[0]; // <- what's the solution here
    
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var imageSrc = e.target.result;
        $('#img_prod' + id).attr('src', imageSrc);
    };
   reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);
});
```

but I get a cannot read property '0' of undefined error. I know the answer is probably on the web, I just have difficulty conceiving the correct search term. Anyway, will you assist me here? I usually code

```
var file = event.target.files[0];
```

and I now don't know how to get the event here. Thanks.

**UPDATE**
The markup for the input element looks like so:

```
<input accept="image/*" title="Choose an image with a 250 x 300 pixel resolution." data-id="2" name="prod_img2" id="prod_img2" type="file" >
```

Comment: The `delegate` method has been deprecated for years. Use `on` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> var selectedFile = $('#prod_img' + id).files[0];
> ```

`files` is a property of a DOM element, not a jQuery object. You need to extract the DOM element from the jQuery object that wraps it:

```
 $('#prod_img' + id)[0].files
```

Comment: your answer didn't work for. I have to use delegate because I'm loading the HTML elements array dynamically and for some reason on doesn't fire events. I got it to work by putting a variable called event in the function's parameter list and calling event.target.files[0];. I marked your answer as answered but the error I got, using your code, says the file was not of type blob. Thank you anyway.

Comment: "I have to use delegate because I'm loading the HTML elements array dynamically " — `on` can handle that.

Comment: "I got it to work by putting a variable called event in the function's parameter list and calling event.target.files[0];" — That sounds like you got the ID wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I got my code to work by adding an event variable like so:

```
$('body').delegate('[id^="prod_img_"]', 'change', function(event) 
{
    event.preventDefault();
    
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
    
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var imageSrc = e.target.result;
        $('#img_prod' + id).attr('src', imageSrc);
    };
   reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);
});
```